# How to skip "Adding ACLs for Paths" step in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a release pipeline in Azure, which uses a Deployment Group type job to deploy a web app to my own Windows VM, on IIS Server.
The app itself is very legacy and certain aspects of it are not written with best practices, which has led to accumulation of too many files and nested folders in the deployment location. We unfortunately cannot get rid of them for now.

While using the "IIS Web Deployment" job in the pipeline, due to the high number of files and folders (think in the scale of millions), the pipeline spends a very long time on a process which seems to be called "`Adding ACLs for path...`" (Line 3173 in the screenshot below, which I eventually had to cancel the pipeline and deploy manually as it was taking too long).

[image: Pipeline execution long]

I have done some research and I know this is taking far too long because there are too many paths inside the deployment folder.

My question is whether there is a way to skip this process, and just have the pipeline deploy files over to the destination, without worrying about all the existing paths? Because what it needs to copy over is actually pretty small. Skipping this process is the ideal solution I am looking for at the moment.

Comment: Adding ACLs for Paths is a step in the Release Pipeline that sets the appropriate permissions on the files and folders being deployed to the target machine. This step is required to ensure that the application can access the files and folders it needs to run correctly. The deployment process involves copying files and folders from the source machine to the target machine. During this process, the "Adding ACLs for Paths" step sets the appropriate permissions on the files and folders being deployed.

Comment: The permissions that are set depend on the type of application being deployed and the user account that the application runs under. For example, if the application runs under the IIS AppPoolIdentity account, the "Adding ACLs for Paths" step will set the appropriate permissions to allow the application to read and write to the files and folders being deployed.

Comment: The "Adding ACLs for Paths" step can take a long time if there are a large number of files and folders being deployed, or if the target machine is underpowered but currently, there is no support to skip ACL check for a particular directory.c

Comment: However you can try this workaround and see if this helps- 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/iis-web-deploy-task-v0-adding-acls-for-path-should/193651

Answer (score 0):

You can try to skip the ACL check in your app following any of the steps below:

1. Add "**`<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>`**" under "**`<PropertyGroup>`**" in the project file of your app (such as **`.csproj`**).
2. When using the [**MSBuild Task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/msbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) to build your app, pass the argument "**`/p:IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination=False`**".
3. When deploying, in the **`.pubxml`** file, add "**`<IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>`**" under "**`<PropertyGroup>`**".

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetACLProviderOnDestination>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: @Behrooz, Is there any update from you?